# Magento2: Mailchimp abandoncart email and data syncing issue

Tags: magento2

Magento data is synching with Mailchimp and abandon cart email is also not working

[image]

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Hello Shomita, Could you tell us how you managed to fix this issue & what the issue was? Thank you!

Comment: Are you getting issue with mailchimp setup?

Comment: Hi Shomita, thanks for replying. Maybe.

Comment: Site has 1000+ subscribers for the mail, only ecommerce data does not seem to work

Comment: Have you set up Cron on your site?

Comment: All Data Sync working fine except Cart still showing zero. Any suggestion ????

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is enable Mailchimp logging and make sure that the syncs are running successfully.

Unless your store is brand new, it is suspicious that no customers/products/orders/carts have synced.

I had a case where a store was completely synced according to the numbers but still marked as "This account is currently syncing". I was able to resolve the problem by manually setting a value in core_config_data for the store's scope and the path "mailchimp/general/issync".

The "This account is currently syncing" error is raised in ***vendor/mailchimp/mc-magento2/Cron/Ecommerce.php*** in the `_processStore` function. For some unknown reason, the core_config_data value was never set for the the store in question.

After going back-and-forth with the extension developer with no luck, I decided to manually create the core_config_value and this solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks.. Issue has been fixed. Can you please look this issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/303422/magento-2-product-images-broken-issue-in-mailchimp-admin/303687#303687?

Comment: can you please tell me? which value did you save for it?

Comment: @SarveshTiwari it looks like I set the current date as the value, in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: I did the same and now it's working for me. thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you magento cron is configured, take a look at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html#create-the-magento-crontab