# Magento 2: Product images broken issue in mailchimp admin

Tags: magento2

I am getting the product images issue in MailChimp admin

Product images are broken, adding CDN link before image link.

Eg:

```
httpd2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/httpabc.com/clients/abc/pub/media/catalog/product/m/u/bwc-37006cs-64_1000_1_.jpg

I don't know how it's adding this link
d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look at https://github.com/mailchimp/mc-magento2/issues/169#issuecomment-377969987
You must specify the right Base URL for User Media Files in the config

[image]

Comment: Which url need to add in textbox?

Comment: I have the added the urls in base url and secure Url..But still getting broken images